# how to create instance of a class to be known at runtime?

Tags: java, reflection

1. How can we we create an object of a class with parametrized
   constructor,and the name of the class would be given to us at the
   run time as command line argument.
2. And what does this line mean

   new Class[]{String.class}
3. and what is the difference between String and String.class ?

Comment: It looks like your second question is answer to your first question. You would just have to add `ctr.newInstance(arguments)`.

Comment: But could some one explain me what's going on in the second question...totaly confusing

Comment: Have you seen documentations of these methods? Which part of it confuses you.

Comment: whats this (new Class[]{String.class})?

Answer (score 0):

> Class c = Class.forName(args[0]);

This gets a `Class<?>` object...

> Constructor ctr = c.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[]{String.class})

and this gets a constructor for that class which argument is a single String.

Once you have that you can invoke `ctr.newInstance(someString)`.

You have a problem though, in that you don't really know the class here. You should at least have an idea of a common subtype, otherwise all you'll ever get is an `Object`...

Answer (score 0):

That JavaDoc for [`Class.getDeclaredConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) is pretty clear:

> Returns a `Constructor` object that reflects the specified constructor of the class or interface represented by this `Class` object. The `parameterTypes` parameter is an array of `Class` objects that identify the constructor's formal parameter types, in declared order.

... so in your case it's getting a `Constructor` object that represents a constructor with one argument, which is a `String` (`new Class[] {String.class}` constructs a `Class[]` with a single entry which is the `Class` object representing `java.lang.String`).  You can call `newInstance("some string")` on that object in order to invoke the constructor and return a new instance of the target class.

In practice you probably need to use `getConstructor` instead of `getDeclaredConstructor` as the latter will return *any* constructor that matches the specified parameter types, including ones that would not normally be accessible from outside (e.g. `private` ones).  Conversely, `getConstructor` will only return `public` constructors.

Answer (score 0):

1- To create a class instance at runtime using reflection :

```
Class classToInstantiate = Class.forName(className);
Constructor<?> theClassInstructor = classToInstantiate.getDeclaredConstructor(<parametersClasses>);
Object instance = theClassInstructor.newInstance(<parameters>);
```

With:

- `parametersClasses` array of the classes of the constructor parameters, for example if the constructor uses a String and an Integer parameter you write :  `getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[]{String.class,Integer.class});`
- `parameters` are the actual values of the parameters to use when instantiating.

Comment: can you explain me why are we writting Class[]{String.class,Integer.class} ??

Comment: the `new Class[]{}` creates and array of objects of type `Class`. These objects represent classes (like String for instance).

Comment: the `Class[]{String.class,Integer.class}` is then creating an array of two Class objects:
-first one is the Class object of the String class
-second one is the Class object of the Integer class

Comment: e.g to instantiate Car I need the number of doors and the car brand name, so my constructor should look like `public Car(String brandName, Integer doors)`, so my constructor needs a `String` and an `Integer` this means that my constructor is `Car(String.class,Integer.class)`. So when using the reflection API you have to specify these two parameter types as an array like `Class[]{String.class,Integer.class}`